# Count of Items in cart not refreshing using AJAX and Java EE

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am trying to update the count of items in my cart , which are stored as a session attribute . The Ajax code for doing it is as follows :
function addItemToUserCart(productId){

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {         
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
        alert("Item added succesfully!!");
        //location.reload();

   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "addItemToCart.action?productId="+productId, true);
  xhttp.send();

}
```

and on the server , I am updating it as follows :

```
String page = "/WEB-INF/pages/menu.jsp";

if (url.endsWith("addItemToCart.action"))
 {
            session.setAttribute("noOfItemsInCart",Integer.valueOf((Integer)session.getAttribute("noOfItemsInCart")) + 1);

request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response);
}
```

But its not updating. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?
JSP:

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;(${sessionScope.noOfItemsInCart}) 
</i> |  <a href="logout.action">Logout</a></span>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions on log?
What happens first time when noOfItemsInCart is null, do you set it up correctly?

Comment: no exceptions. In fact, if i check the updated count on the servlet , it is updated but it is not reflected on the JSP.Yes i am initializing attribute with 0.

Comment: Please add your JSP code.